# Why an object declared in method is subject to garbage collection before the method returns?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Consider an object declared in a method:

```
public void foo() {
    final Object obj = new Object();

    // A long run job that consumes tons of memory and 
    // triggers garbage collection
}
```

Will obj be subject to garbage collection *before* foo() returns?

**UPDATE**: 
Previously I thought obj is not subject to garbage collection *until* foo() returns.

However, today I find myself wrong.

I have spend several hours in fixing a bug and finally found the problem is caused by obj garbage collected!

Can anyone explain why this happens? And if I want obj to be pinned how to achieve it?

Here is the code that has problem.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://<whatever>";

        // I find wrap is gc-ed somewhere
        SqlConnection wrap = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 

        Connection con = wrap.currentConnection();
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
             ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select instance_id, doc_id from
               crawler_archive.documents");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int instanceID = rs.getInt(1);
            int docID = rs.getInt(2);

            if (docID % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println(docID);
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        //wrap.close();
    }
}
```

After running the Java program, it will print the following message before it crashes:

```
161000
161000
********************************
Finalizer CALLED!!
********************************
********************************
Close CALLED!!
********************************
162000
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
```

And here is the code of class SqlConnection:

```
class SqlConnection
{
    private final String connectionString;
    private Connection connection;

    public SqlConnection(String connectionString) {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public synchronized Connection currentConnection() throws SQLException {
        if (this.connection == null || this.connection.isClosed()) {
            this.closeConnection();
            this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        }
        return this.connection;
    }

    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try {
            System.out.println("********************************");
            System.out.println("Finalizer CALLED!!");
            System.out.println("********************************");
            this.close();
        } finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        System.out.println("********************************");
        System.out.println("Close CALLED!!");
        System.out.println("********************************");
        this.closeConnection();
    }

    protected void closeConnection() {
        if (this.connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
            } finally {
                this.connection = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not printing out the message in `finalize()`, you're printing it out in `close()`, and you're calling `close()` yourself. Move the message into the finalizer itself, and try again.

Comment: You should post a separate question for your update.

Comment: @skaffman: I should remove the close() from the main. The problem still persists.

Comment: Your code remains confusing. Rearrange the println stuff to put them in the finalizer.

Comment: @skatffman: I have updated the code. It should look more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your code is **written** the object pointed to by "wrap" shouldn't be eligible for garbage collection until "wrap" pops off the stack at the end of the method.

The fact that it is being collected suggests to me your code **as compiled** doesn't match the original source and that the compiler has done some optimisation such as changing this:

```
SqlConnection wrap = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
Connection con = wrap.currentConnection();
```

to this:

```
Connection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString).currentConnection();
```

(Or even inlining the whole thing) because "wrap" isn't used beyond this point.  The anonymous object created would be eligible for GC immediately.

The only way to be sure is to decompile the code and see what's been done to it.

Comment: I find this is the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I'm genuinely astonished by this, but you're right. It's easily reproducible, you don't need to muck about with database connections and the like:

```
public class GcTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting");

        Object dummy = new GcTest(); // gets GC'd before method exits

        // gets bigger and bigger until heap explodes
        Collection<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();

        // method never exits normally because of while loop
        while (true) {
            collection.add(new String("test"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Finalizing instance of GcTest");
    }
}
```

Runs with:

```
Starting
Finalizing instance of GcTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:351)
    at test.GcTest.main(GcTest.java:22)
```

Like I said, I can hardly believe it, but there's no denying the evidence.

It does make a perverse kind of sense, though, the VM will have figured out that the object is never used, and so gets rid of it. This must be permitted by the spec.

Going back to the question's code, you should never rely on `finalize()` to clean up your connections, you should *always* do it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

There are really two different things happening here.  `obj` is a stack variable being set to a reference to the `Object`, and the `Object` is allocated on the heap.  The stack will just be cleared (by stack pointer arithmetic).

But yes, the `Object` itself will be cleared by garbage collection.  All heap-allocated objects are subject to GC.

EDIT: To answer your more specific question, the Java spec does not guarantee collection *by* any particular time (see [the JVM spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html)) (of course it will be collected *after* its last use).  So it's only possible to answer for specific implementations.

EDIT: Clarification, per comments

Comment: It doesn't guarantee a time BUT that doesn't mean it will randomly collect your object whenever even if it is still in scope ;)

Comment: @Paolo - the problem here is that it is out of scope after the last time it's used (not when it drops off the stack)

Comment: And optmisations may make last use time surprising.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm sure you're aware, in Java Garbage Collection and Finialization are non-deterministic.  All you can determine in this case is when `wrap` is *eligible* for garbage collection.  I'm assuming you are asking if `wrap` only becomes eligible for GC when the method returns (and `wrap` goes out of scope).  I think that some JVMs (e.g. HotSpot with `-server`) won't wait for the object reference to be popped from the stack, it will make it eligible for GC as soon as nothing else references it.  It looks like this is what you are seeing.

To summarise, you are relying on finalization being slow enough to not finalize the instance of `SqlConnection` before the method exits.  You finalizer is closing a resource that the `SqlConnection` is no longer responsible for.  Instead, you should let the `Connection` object be responsible for its own finalization.

Comment: @Ben Lings: actually the close() method made public is to let the user explicitly dispose the object. However, if the user forgets to close() the object, the finalizer acts as the last guard to release the resource. This is much similar to the .NET dispose design model.

Comment: The problem is that your finalizer is cleaning up a resource that it isn't responsible for.

Answer (score 1):

> Will obj be subject to garbage collection before foo() returns?

You cannot be sure `obj` will be collected before `foo` returns but it is certainly eligible for collection before `foo` returns.

> Can anyone explain why this happens?

GCs collect unreachable objects. Your object is likely to become unreachable before `foo` returns.

Scope is irrelevant. The idea that `obj` stays on the stack until `foo` returns is an overly-simplistic mental model. Real systems don't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `obj` is a local variable in the method and it is popped off the stack as soon as the method returns or exits. This leaves no way to reach the `Object` object on the heap and hence it will be garbage collected. And the `Object` object on the heap will be GC'd only after its reference `obj` is popped off the stack,ie, only after the method finishes or returns.

**EDIT:** 
To answer your update,

```
UPDATE: Let me make the question more clear. 
Will obj be subject to garbage collection before foo() returns?
```

`obj` is just a **reference** to the **actual object** on the **heap**. Here `obj` is declared inside the method foo(). So your question `Will obj be subject to garbage collection before foo() returns?` doesnot apply as `obj` goes inside the stack frame when the method `foo()` is running and is gone when the method finishes.

Comment: obj is a reference type, so only the reference (the pointer) is stored on the stack, the actual data is in the heap.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens, thats exactly what I mentioned. The reference variable obj is a LOCAL VARIABLE.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't read the tags. Thinking of .net. (I've edited so I can revoke my downvote). Sorry.

Comment: Simon, this aspect (stack reference variables, heap objects) is the same for both Java and C# (though other things, like `KeepAlive`, are *not*).

Comment: @Matthew, yeah, I'd guess there are a lot of similarities, that's probably why I so easily mixed up the question in the first place - the terminology is exactly the same, but I haven't done any Java in years so I'm totally unqualified to even comment, hence I've deleted my answer.

Comment: Actually there's another caveat to my previous comment.  C# has value types like DateTime that can be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

According to the current spec, there isn't even a *happens-before* ordering from finalisation to normal use. So, to impose order, you actually need to use a lock, a volatile or, if you are desperate, stashing a reference reachable from a static. There is certainly nothing special about scope.

It should be rare that you actually need to write a finaliser.