# In java what happens to an Object after a static method has returned

Tags: java, memory

I have an `Object` that occupies a large chunk of memory, I pass the object into a static helper method for processing. What does the JVM do with the `Object` after the method returns?

```
public class Helper {
    public static boolean processObject(Object object) {
        // Do something with object
        return true;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Object object = new Object(); // large object created
if (Helper.processObject(object)) {
    // do something
}
```

My concern is that the large object will stick around in memory for longer than if it was processed in the same class.

Comment: It will stick around as long as there is still a reference to it. Once the last reference goes out of scope it can be garbage collected

Comment: Since you are using a static method without any class variables, the large object won't be saved in the class. Thus, you will not have a memory leak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will stick around as long as there is still a reference to it. Once the last reference goes out of scope it can be garbage collected (but it won't nessissary be collected immediately). I have expanded your example to more clearly demonstrate

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] largeArray=new int[1000][10000]; // large object created

    use(largeArray);

    //object still retained

    while(true){

    }

}

public static void use(int[][] in){

}
```

[image]

This is usually fine. But you could allow it to be collected earlier by not holding on to the reference at all

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    use(new int[1000][10000]);

    while(true){

    }

}

public static void use(int[][] in){

}
```

[image]

Equally explicitly nulling out the variable would also allow it to be collected earlier.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] largeArray=new int[1000][10000];

    use(new int[1000][10000]);

    largeArray=null;

    while(true){

    }

}
```

**Usually this isn't worth worrying about**, but if the other code is in a long loop it might be (although thats probably a sign you need to refactor your code)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the compiler is smart enough to do that optimization on its own.

Comment: @Ordous You would have thought so but interestingly not. I've profiled and [this is when the reference is kept](http://imgur.com/dCInjky) with an infinity while loop to keep us in the method and [this is where no reference is kept](http://imgur.com/RBZ7kw3)

Comment: Huh, I'm surprised. I would have though that if it can do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482540/why-an-object-declared-in-method-is-subject-to-garbage-collection-before-the-met), then it can also inline object creation into a method call.

Comment: @Ordous An issue is probably that the compiler has options. Probably in that case it did some other optimisation and caused a (desirable) side effect.